# Get parent directory of file in batch using non-full windows file path

Tags: svn, batch-file

I am trying to develop the script that is used on pre-commite basis for svn.

Here is the batch code:

```
svn st | grep "M " | cut -c 8- > modified.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (modified.txt) do (
  if not %%A==. (
    if %%A==%%A (
      set "filepath=%%A" 
      for /f "delims==" %%F in (%filepath%) do (
        set "foldername=%%~nF"
        echo "Parent Found %foldername% from %filepath%..."
      )
      pause 
      del "\\<intranet share>\<folder>\%foldername%\%%A"
      svn export ".\%%A" "\\<intranet share>\<folder>\%foldername%"
    )
  )
)
```

The output is like this:

> C:\Work\>(
>   
> set "foldername="
>   
>  echo "Found  from C:\Work\repo_path\file_name.php..."
>   )

As you can see, the variable next to `Found` is empty. Where is the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I deleted my answer, 'because it didn't work out

Comment: 1. You have `svnlook` in pre-commit hooks. 2. Describe your **business-task** in plain words, I'm too lazy to grok your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Hence, before the for /f statement, insert a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` **and** wherever in the loop you have `%var%`, change this to `!var!`. This does **not** apply to the metavariable (loop-control variable) `%%A` or `%%F`.

Note also your statement `if %%A==%%A...` - now `%%A`, if cmd plays nicely, should always equal `%%A`, so this seems like a superfluous test. **But** there is a danger in this construct. Since you are using `tokens=*`, it's possible that `%%A` will contain a separator - classically a space. If this happens, `cmd` will see `if two words==two words...` and have conniptions. You can guard against this with `if "%%A"=="%%A"`.